# Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, swiperefreshlayout

I'm trying to implement SwipeRefreshLayout as per this post: http://nlopez.io/swiperefreshlayout-with-listview-done-right/

So now my XML looks like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/match_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#999999"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent">

    </ListView>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        layout="@layout/empty_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

When debugging my app I get this error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
```

when I get to this line in my fragments onCreateView:

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(matchType.getLayout(), container, false);
```

My SDK Manager reports that everything should be updated so I'm really at wits end...

Please help...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't u use the xml layout file instead of that matchType.getLayout() is there some reason for that

Comment: No particular reason. It's some rather old code that was working before I wrapped my ListView in the SwipeRefreshLayout... Also I'm not especially experienced in Android so I wouldn't know how :-)

Comment: Change that xml file for R.layout.filename just try should work.

Comment: Now I know! It's because I have different match types with different layouts...

Comment: can u please provide the link to the code

Comment: Mind u this is my sandbox for learning Android. There two main things I would like to do: 1. Have one common layout shared by all five sports instead of one for each (identical) - a nut I haven't cracked yet and 2. Better refresh logic: Each time the app is started and then swipe down (which is why I'm looking into SwipeRefreshLayout)

Comment: Took the code down again...